# Edge-colourability of $K_7$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider $K_7$ , i.e a complete graph of size $7$. I was wondering whether we can represent it as the union of 7 monochromatic triangles of 7 different colours such that no two edges of two different triangles overlap.

---

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Here’s one way to do this. Label the nodes in $K_7$ as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. Now form seven triangles of the form $(n, n+1, n+3)$, all done modulo 7. These triangles partition $K_7$ and have no overlap.

More generally, a way to decompose $K_n$ into triangles is called a [Steiner triple system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Steiner_triple_systems), and they exist for all $n$ congruent to either 1 or 3 mod 6.